# Integrate nodejs into existing docker lamp container

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, lamp, laravel-breeze

I'm currently learning how to use docker. And i have a lamp stack container, including php7.4, apache, mariadb, phpmyadmin. All is working fine. I installed Laravel into this container. It includes all needed php extensions.
(I'm aware of Laravel Sail, for docker learning purposes i prefer not to use Sail. I prefer to use my own container).
One problem i'm facing now is i try to install Laravel Breeze and i need to use npm commands at some point. But i couldn't manage to install nodejs into my container and i can use some help.

This is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/${PHPVERSION}
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${PHPVERSION}'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT}:443"
    links: 
      - database
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
    environment:
      PMA_PORT: ${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_PORT}
  database:
    build:
      context: "./bin/${DATABASE}"
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-database'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '${HOST_MACHINE_PMA_PORT}:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
  redis:
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

I'm pulling some variables from .env file and others from several Dockerfiles.

I want to integrate nodejs but not for serious nodejs programming. Only for some Laravel based situations like running 'npm install', 'npm run dev' etc. I won't be needing extra details. And i guess it should run on the same volume with the php image.